# How to pass querystring data to template?

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

I have following controller:

```
Controller.extend({

    login: function(params,route,query){
        console.log(query.query);
        var model = new LoginModel();
        this.view = new LoginView({ region: 'main', model: model });
    },
});
```

1. How to obtain querystring data in controller action? Above I am just taking the third argument of action and it contains `querystring` object. Is there better/nicer method?
2. How I can pass this data to view and then to template?

Answer (score 0):

> How to obtain querystring data in controller action? Above I am just
>   taking the third argument of action and it contains querystring
>   object. Is there better/nicer method?

I think that's probably the cleanest way.

> How I can pass this data to view and then to template?

From the [chaplin.js source code](http://chaplinjs.org/annotated/view.html#section-21):

```
module.exports = class View extends Backbone.View
  ...
  constructor: (options) ->
      # Copy some options to instance properties.
      if options
        for optName, optValue of options when optName in @optionNames
          this[optName] = optValue
          ...
```

When you pass options to the view constructor:

```
new LoginView({ region: 'main', model: model });
```

The options become attributes of the view so in the view methods you can call those like:

```
this.region
this.model
```

So you can pass an extra option:

```
new LoginView({ region: 'main', model: model, query : query });
```

And override the function `getTemplateFunction` in your view to build the view URL dynamically and be able to pass the query values.

```
getTemplateFunction: function() {
  // You can access this.query here
  // Get template via Ajax
  // Compile and return template
  return Handlebars.compile(templateStr);
}
```

You can find full details about `getTemplateFunction` [here](http://chaplinjs.org/annotated/view.html#section-65).

If what you want is to add query to the model you can look at `getTemplateData` instead [here](http://chaplinjs.org/annotated/view.html#section-63).

Hope it helps!